# Powershell move-item access denied

Tags: powershell, move

Running a PS form with a button.  Button press does some stuff then calls a module.  I need to move a folder from D:\FolderName01\MyFolderName to D:\FolderName02 using the module.

I am logged in as Administrator.  Server 2012-R2

The code does **NOT** run when invoked from a button press and the automated script runs.

It **DOES** run without problem when I am editing the code, I highlight it and use "Run Selection".

This is literally the entire module.  Nothing else is being done.

Code:

```
 function MoveTheFolder($VariableName){

    if ( -not (Test-Path "D:\FolderName02") ) {
       md "D:\FolderName02"}

    cd -Path d:\
    Move-Item -Path "D:\FolderName01\$VariableName" -Destination "D:\FolderName02" -Force

 }
```

FolderName02 is created without issue.  $VariableName is passed in to the module and is correct based on a breakpoint analysis and the actual error message.  The original path is a DVD drive (.iso file on F:).

Error given is

```
move-item: Access to the path '[D:\FolderName01\$VariableName]' is denied.
```

I can move the folders manually using Windows Explorer, so they do not appear to be tied up with open applications.

Comment: is the script being "Run As Administrator" if UAC is enabled? can you write the path with variable out to the console or a message box to ensure its processing the path correctly?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you use `COPY` instead of `move-item` does the directory get copied to the destination?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler he's not moving from the DVD.  The DVD is the F:\ not the D:\, right?

Comment: @Nate - Copy does work, but there is 20GB+ of data.  Copy takes minutes to do while move is instant.

The D:\ Drive is on the HD.  The script is being run from the F:\ Drive.

ssaviers - I've confirmed that the variable is correct at a breakpoint just before the move-item call.  Also the variable name is in the actual error message.

Comment: UAC is disabled in the registry (EnableLUA = 0)

Comment: The error message calls out the name of the folder given, not $VariableName.  So if the folder being moved is D:\Folder01\PEBCAK, $VariableName = PEBCAK, and the error shown is "Access to the path D:\Folder01\PEBCAK is denied"

Comment: So just to be sure it's not permissions, do you want to try setting the parent folder of `$VariableName` to give "EVERYONE" full access to its child items?  Or if you're using ISE, close it and reopen it as admin?  It still sounds like a permissions issue if you can move it through explorer.exe but not through the script.

Comment: That seems odd that your error text states `'[D:\FolderName01\$VariableName]'` where it should have been whatever the variable was. That cmdlet parameter is using double quotes correct? You verify the destination but not the source. Does test path work against the source?

Comment: Matt - Yeah poor initial wording on my part.  The error does not reference the variable name, but rather its actual value.  Also, Folder01 always exists based in the system build; it is integral to the design, and the path is correct.

Comment: Nate - Added Everyone with Full Control, still no good.  Same error.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell 2.0 you will need to make the directory before the copy.

In PowerShell 3.0 you do not need to create, because the Move-Item or Copy-Item will make that for you.

As far as getting the files. We can use the `Get-ChildItem` with the switch `-Recurse`, because it will grab all the files in the first directory included the subfolders. Once we grab the files and folders we pipe it to the `Move-Item` with the option `-Force`. Note the Move-Item will move the files to the new directory. If this is what you want then we need to use `Copy-Item`. I have also added the `-Verbose` switch for debugging. Let us know what files are not working.

```
Function MoveTheFolder($VariableName){
if ( -not (Test-Path "D:\FolderName02") ) {New-Item "D:\FolderName02\$VariableName" -Type Directory}
        cd D:\ #You do not need this, but its ok. 
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\FolderName01\$VariableName\*" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "D:\FolderName02\$VariableName" -Force -Verbose
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\FolderName01\$VariableName\*" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "D:\FolderName02\$VariableName" -Force -Verbose
        }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It did NOT make D:\Folder02 if it did not exist, so I'll need to keep that check in there.  The rest sort of works, but not correctly yet.  The files in $VariableName are pulled from their respective sub folders and placed into the root of D:\Folder02\$VariableName.  I need the entire $VariableName folder moved from Folder01 to Folder02.  And there are lots of other folders in Folder01 that should not be moved.

Comment: That was my fault, didn't know at the time that it didn't work for PowerShell V2.0. My understanding now is that directory Folder1 has a lot of sub-folders. We only want the directory that equals to $VariableName. Then you want FolderName02 to place files into another foldername $VariableName.  I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

So Zach's solution, while not completely correct did lead me to the actual answer.  Here is the working code:

```
Function MoveTheFolder($VariableName){
    if ( -not (Test-Path "D:\FolderName02") ) {
        New-Item "D:\FolderName02\$VariableName" -Type Directory
    }
    Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\FolderName01\$VariableName\" | Move-Item -Destination "D:\FolderName02\$VariableName" -Force
    Remove-Item -Path "D:\Folder01\$VariableName" -Force
}
```

Got rid of the wildcard signifier and -recurse because all I want is the folder names, no need to enumerate the files therein.